# I want to read custom format data from excel using apache POI.while reading the custom text from excel it gives error. ""

Tags: spring, apache, model-view-controller, apache-poi

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value
>   from a text cell  at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:888)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getDateCellValue(XSSFCell.java:621)
>     at
>   com.bvm.controller.MainController.ExcelProcessing(MainController.java:117)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`

Code Sample:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="processExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ExcelProcessing(Model model, @RequestParam("excelfile") MultipartFile excelfile)
    {
        try {
            List<ExcelHeatModel> lstheatdata = new ArrayList<>();
             int i = 1;
            // Creates a workbook object from the uploaded excelfile
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelfile.getInputStream());
            // Creates a worksheet object representing the first sheet
            XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);





            // Reads the data in excel file until last row is encountered
                while (i <= worksheet.getLastRowNum()) {
                    // Creates an object for the Excel Heat Model
                    ExcelHeatModel heatdata = new ExcelHeatModel();
                    // Creates an object representing a single row in excel
                    XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i++);

                    // Sets the Read data to the model class            
                    heatdata.setTaskid((int)(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue())); //reading numeric value from excel
                    System.out.println(heatdata.getTaskid());


    heatdata.setCustomername(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue()); //reading string value
                    System.out.println(heatdata.getCustomername());


//in the below code i  am receiving error. 

                     DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();     
                     String cellAsStr = formatter.formatCellValue((Cell) row.getCell(14).getDateCellValue());

                    heatdata.setAcceptedon(cellAsStr);      
                    System.out.println(heatdata.getAcceptedon());
```

Comment: Which line is line 117 in your MainController.java? If it is `String cellAsStr = formatter.formatCellValue((Cell) row.getCell(14).getDateCellValue());` then in column `O` of your current row is not a date but text content. Btw.: Even if a date would be there, you would get `ClassCastException` since you cannot cast `Date` to `Cell`. It should be  `String cellAsStr = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(14));`

Comment: .Thank you Alex for response. I have date and time in my excel sheet cell  "10/5/2016 9:48" but it's format is custom in excel sheet.

Comment: I tried your code and it's giving me same error "Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell"

Comment: From which line is the error thrown? It cannot be `String cellAsStr = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(14));`.

Comment: Actually the format of excel cell and format apache poi fetching is mismatch, hence I am getting error. Thats is why I am getting error at 117 line. Can you tell me way for parsing Custom format value from Excel. where value of cell is date time format m/d/yyyy h:mm

Comment: "...the format of excel cell and format apache poi fetching is mismatch, hence I am getting error." No, the error you have shown is about text content versus numeric content in the cell. Please show the correct error and the code line which throws that error and what exact content is in the cell.

Comment: controller code at line 117 and 118:(i have changed a code a bit)                                                                             heatdata.setAcceptedon(row.getCell(14).getNumericCellValue());
System.out.println(heatdata.getAcceptedon());

Comment: error Log:                                                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:888)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:221)
 at com.bvm.controller.MainController.ExcelProcessing(MainController.java:117)

Comment: So your cell `row.getCell(14)` (column `O` in current row) contains text and that's why `row.getCell(14).getNumericCellValue()‌` throws that error.

Comment: but its not working with string, date, numeric .. So Now how can i fetch that value I have tried all, getNumericCellValue, getStringCellValue, getDateCellValue, everying... Please tell me is there any way??

Comment: What is `System.out.println(row.getCell(14).toString());` printing?

Comment: Thank you brother you are remarkable!!! I used your method and modified code. Please see code in below comment. But Thanks a lot.. Appreciate all your time..

Comment: String val = row.getCell(14).toString();
heatdata.setAcceptedon(val);
System.out.println(heatdata.getAcceptedon());

Comment: output is : 21-Jul-2016